# Windows proxy supporting connection to proxy PAC

Tags: windows, networking

I'm in a corporate environment where proxy is done using [proxy auto-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).

As most of the software I use don't support this method, I would like to install a local proxy that would allow other software to connect transparently.

The most typical scenario is java/groovy code, which can only support proxyHost/proxyPort.

As a consequence, I'm looking for a freeware/open-source software service that would use the PAC of my company, but act as local proxy.

Do you know such a software ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) provides exactly the feature : using my PAC config for applications that do not support PAC.